# Salt in argon2d as proof-of-work algorithm

Tags: scrypt, argon2

I want to use argon2d as a proof-of-work algorithm. But as I know I can't use the algorithm without salt? Should I use a static salt for every task or generate new? Is it possible to increase algorithm performance in case of static salt using? What is the perfect pattern of using such algorithms as argon2/scrypt for this purposes?

Comment: If a salt is really not necessary for your use-case, you do not need to use one. You can give argon2d a null salt (salt composed entirely of \x00). The Python `hashlib` library allows you to set a 0-byte length salt.